# How to make interpolation with SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I want to make color interpolation with SLD on Geoserver. [Interpolation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-tipstricks/transformation-func.html#interpolate) works fine. But i need to know min, middle and max property values to make it correct. So i want to know this values, i says:

```
  <LineSymbolizer>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">
             <ogc:Function name="Interpolate">
               <!-- Property to transform -->
               <ogc:PropertyName>AverageDailyIntensCar</ogc:PropertyName>

               <!-- Mapping curve definition pairs (input, output) -->
               <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
               <ogc:Literal>#fefeee</ogc:Literal>

               <!--<ogc:Literal>15000</ogc:Literal>-->
               <ogc:Div>
                 <ogc:Function name="max">
                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>AverageDailyIntensCar</ogc:PropertyName>
                 </ogc:Function>
                 <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
               </ogc:Div>
               <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>

               <!-- <ogc:Literal>-->
                  <ogc:Function name="max">
                    <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>AverageDailyIntensCar</ogc:PropertyName>
                 </ogc:Function>
              <!-- </ogc:Literal>-->
               <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>

               <!-- Interpolation method -->
               <ogc:Literal>color</ogc:Literal>
               <!-- Interpolation mode - defaults to linear -->
             </ogc:Function>
           </CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
```

Have no validation errors, but in layer preview i get all features with same colors.
My main problem is a middle value:

```
               <ogc:Div>
             <ogc:Function name="max">
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:PropertyName>AverageDailyIntensCar</ogc:PropertyName>
             </ogc:Function>
             <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:Div>
           <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>
```

Here something wrong becouse when i use Litteral for middle value interpolation works fine and i get features with differend colors.
 Whats wrong here?

Comment: What is the maximum value from `AverageDailyIntensCar` field?

Comment: What happens if you remove `<ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>` beneath `<ogc:Function name="max">` in both the second and third control points (middle and max). Because I am not sure you need those literal since it will already take max from range of values in `AverageDailyIntensCar` field.